# Is the antecedent of a relative pronoun in a prepositional 'of' phrase a matter of choice?For example,

Tags: verbs, agreement

1. The bag of books that was found belongs to me.
2. The bag of books that talk about history belong to me.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's not quite a matter of choice, but it is ambiguous. This is what is called an "attachment ambiguity", and it's common in right-branching languages like English, because long constituents are often chained at the end of a sentence, and may have been attached to several possible constituents.

Comment: Why is @JohnLawler 's answer put in the comments? Comments are for requests for clarification, not (good) answers.

Comment: It's put there because that's where I wrote it. Contrary to official mythology, answers are no more easy to find than comments; nobody can find stuff in either place. So I have adopted the practice of answering simple questions in comments. Because it's simpler for me and no worse for others.